# Cannot boot Kubuntu (NvidiaGTX970): error noveau MMIO write of 80000102 FAULT at 10eb14

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, kubuntu

I've been trying to install the latest Kubuntu from USB flash drive on my PC. Once I choose the default installation at the boot menu I end up with an error:

```
[   4.347654] nouveau 0000:01:00.0 bus: MMIO write of 80000102 FAULT at 10eb14 [IBUS]
```

The USB drive is fine; the Kubuntu installation menu shows up properly on laptop.

From what I searched, it has something to do with nvidia drivers, but I haven't found any proper explanation of how to fix this. Got latest drivers on NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970.

unetbootin menu:

[image]

error content:

[image]